# window.location.href not working, can't redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I've been trying to put a window.location.href to work, but I can't see to make it to redirect my page.

Here is the code:

```
$('#filtrar').click(function() {
    var pai = document.getElementById("pai");
    var filho = document.getElementById("filho");
    var marca = document.getElementById("pages");

    var value_pai = pai.options[pai.selectedIndex].text;
    var value_filho = filho.options[filho.selectedIndex].text;
    var value_marca = marca.options[marca.selectedIndex].text;

    newLink = 'categorias.php?';
    if ((value_filho != "----") && (value_filho != "selecionar categoria"))
    {
        filho_link = filho.value;
        newLink += "categ=" + filho_link + "&";

    } 
    else if (value_pai != "selecionar categoria")
    {
        pai_link = pai.value;
        newLink += "categ=" + pai_link + "&";
    }

    if (value_marca != "selecionar marca")
    {
        marca_link = marca.value;
        newLink += "marca=" + marca_link + "&";
    }

    newLink = newLink.slice(0, -1);
    window.location.href = newLink;
});
```

It might not be the case, but I'm also using ajax on this page to refresh one dropdown list that gives data for the refresh.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you checked what `newLink` contains ?

Comment: why dont you try just  location.href = newLink;

Comment: Try `console.log(newLink);` to see what it is set to

Comment: Did you try `window.location.assign("Page.aspx") ?`

Comment: @Subin that is exactly the same as what he is doing.

Comment: if you use chrome dev tools or firebug etc, put a break at `window.location.href = newLink;` and tell us what `newLink` equals. or use `console.log(newLink)` to output the value.

Comment: @KristofFeys it's better to use `console.log()` for debugging purposes, because `alert()` modifies the flow and can cause a bug to disappear.

Comment: Will everybody please stop making the same point! This isn't helping!

Comment: i've used an alert early and the value is what I need "categorias.php?categ=2" for exemple. also there are no erros on console log, and by doing breaks on the code, there are no erros that are shown to me

Comment: where's the ajax code? That's probably where your issue lies.

Comment: I found the problem. I was using a form with post method, and It was canceling my redirect on Jquery, I think that someone here on the comments helped me see this error, but cant find comment. Thanks

Comment: What about the method you're using? Any examples on that?
Edit: nevermind, we've got the same idea exactly. Good it worked out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a problem when I used a form with post method on the button, and so, It would refresh the page and no redirect it the way it should